# CSS Animation and Transform

Tags: css

I am not sure why the `transform: translateX` is not working on my animation.  I am trying to move a div 100px and then backwards to the starting spot.

Here is a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/tWnRb/

Here is my HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: coral;
  -webkit-animation: squareToCircle 2s 1s infinite alternate;

}

-webkit-keyframes squareToCircle {
  0% {
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    background: coral;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  25% {
    border-radius: 50% 0 0 0;
    background: darksalmon;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  50% {
    border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
    background: hotpink;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  75% {
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
    background: lightcoral;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  100% {
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
    background: darksalmon;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

Comment: you missed the `@` before `-keyframes` http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/tWnRb/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

keyframes need to be prefixed with @

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tWnRb/7/)

```
@-webkit-keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION { }
@-moz-keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION { }
@-o-keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION { }
@keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION { }
```

You also should accomodate other browsers as well as webkit.

Comment: Thank you!  I did not realize it needed the `@`

Comment: Thanks again!  I will add the vendor prefixes, I just left them off to make the example code easier to debug :)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/tWnRb/5/

```
-webkit-keyframes squareToCircle {
```

to

```
@-webkit-keyframes squareToCircle {
```

Comment: Thanks!  I did not realize the `@` was needed!  Small syntax errors always seem to get me when i'm tyring to learn something new.  Thanks again!

Comment: go with Obsidion's answer - his is more complete